# Unity - how to show world space canvas above screen overlay canvas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, basically I have a world space canvas (that currently uses a different camera) and a screen space canvas. In the screen space canvas I have a blur material from the asset store on a plane, which only works in screen space.

I need to do a switch where I still have that blurred background and the button to get back, but on top I have my world space canvas (the "text" objects below):

[image]

Setting clear flags to none on the second camera allows me to see what the first camera sees, but not its canvas. Is the best option here to screen capture the first camera's canvas?

Or is there a way to not make the screen space canvas block the world space?

Comment: You could add a CanvasGroup on it and temporarily disable it.

Comment: Part of the issue here is how you want the world space canvases and other world space objects to behave.

For example, if you have a rock, then a canvas, then another rock, partially behind each other, then do you want both rocks blurred, but not the canvas?

If that's the case, you have a problem, since those world space canvases are rendered in the same pass as the rocks; so you need some kind of post-processing shader to specifically not blur the canvases... when they're visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you have 2 Cameras let's say:

- `MainCamera`: for displaying 3D content
- `ScreenSpaceCamera`: for only displaying that Screenspace "plane".

and what you want is: Always display the 3D content on top of the ScreenSpace content, right?

---

So what you can do is creating a special [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) e.g. `ScreenSpace` and than

- `MainCamera` -> `Camera`:
- `Depth` = `0` (higher value means drawn on top)
- `ClearFlags` = `DepthOnly`
- `CullingMask` = Everything **except** `ScreenSpace`

[image]

- `ScreenSpaceCamera` -> `Camera`:
- `Depth` = -1 (so it is drawn behind depth level 0)
- `ClearFlags` = Nothing (or whatever you want)
- `CullingMask` = **only** `ScreenSpace`

[image]

---

As you can see now the 3D content (RedImage) is always drawn on top of the ScreenSpace (white).

[image]

---

Note: In case you want to be able to switch that `Screenspace` on and off you need an additional Camera that actually clears the image! As you can see in the `Camera Preview` that camera's buffer is not "cleared" (because we told it so).

So if you would disable the `Screenspace` you would get what you see in the preview box! -> not good ^^

I would simply add a 3rd camera e.g. `BackgroundCamera` as child of the `MainCamera` (so it is automatically moved correctly) and give it

- `Depth` = -2 (so behind the ScreenSpace)
- `ClearFlags` = e.g. `SkyBox`
- `CullingMask` = Nothing (so you really only render the background here)

---

If you have something more complex in mind like e.g.

- ontop UI (depth 0)
- ScreenSpace (depth -1)
- other 3D content 
  let those be rendered by the `ScreenSpaceCamera` instead. So if you diactivate the Blurr Canvas they are displayed normal, otherwise blurred.
- Background (depth -2)

simply extend the example with 4 Cameras, Depths and different Layers.

Comment: Thank you. Now only problem is the 3d world I have behind my 3d ui elements is still interactive. Any way to disable interaction on what Camera 1 is seeing?

Comment: Hmm this pretty much depends on how exactly you interact with stuff .... It it is UI stuff afaik if you disable the `Raycaster` component on the camera you can't interact with it anymore but I'm not sure