# Unity - How to display World space canvas above Screen space overlay canvas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas

I have a simple setup with some main UI being displayed on a screen space overlay canvas, and have a world space canvas attached to an object in 3D space.

The issue I have is that the World Space canvas is rendered underneath the Screen space one. How can I make it so the world space canvas is always rendered above the main UI's screen space canvas ?

I'm using a single camera set in orthographic mode if that's of any use.

EDIT: One solution is to do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407632/unity-how-to-show-world-space-canvas-above-screen-overlay-canvas) as suggested by [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo). Basically adding another camera only looking at the world space canvas.

EDIT 2 : Another solution I found, and is much simpler I think is to set the canvas attached to my object to Screen space overlay, and have the anchored position of the previously world space UI set using `Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position)` where "transform" refers to the object's transform in 3D space. Doing this allows me to set the rendering order of this screen space overlay canvas to any value I want.

Comment: There's a reason it's called "Screen Space *Overlay*".  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because it's completely attached to an object in 3D space. It will move around with the object, as you would expect from a world space canvas. But I have some stuff blocking clicks in the Overlay canvas that I would like to avoid by rendering the world canvas above.

Comment: Ahh. And you still want the screen space stuff to receive clicks, but as a secondary priority.  Is that it?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have my main UI in the screen space, so I want it to receive clicks, but when the world space stuff is around, I want this to take priority and in case 2 buttons align, the world space button should be on top and receive the click

Comment: Please see the duplicate link. It is the same principle: You will need at least two Cameras